# Collinearity condition in plane

Tags: geometry, affine-geometry

Let $P_1,..,P_n$ be $n$ points in  plane such that every line $P_i P_j$ contains another $P_k$. Show that the given points are collinear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. By the [Sylvester–Gallai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%E2%80%93Gallai_theorem) theorem, given a finite number of points in the plane, either all the points are collinear or
there is a line which contains exactly two of the points.